# OSRF FRC 2016 Competition

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey, I'd like to know whether is there a code available for OSRF FRC 2016 Competition?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20679/osrf-frc-2016-competition/) by [andreinkfemust](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6913/andreinkfemust/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The code is hosted here, but beware that it hasn't been maintained for 2 years:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/frc2016_competition

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andreinkfemust](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6913/andreinkfemust/) on 2018-10-20**:
unfortunately, I have 'access denied' for this repo ...:<

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-10-22**:
I just made the repository public. Have fun :)

**Comment by [andreinkfemust](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6913/andreinkfemust/) on 2018-10-27**:
thank you! love, peace, and robots!